# Why is "nil" value for numbers 0?

Tags: go

The "`nil`" value for a string `""` makes sense to me but `0` is a legitimate number. For instance, the number of people in a room can be `0` but a person's name cannot be `""`. What was the reasoning behind this convention?

**(Edit) Additional info:**

What I would like to do is have a way of testing if a value has been set for a number. Having someone's name set to `""` is obviously not correct, whereas having an integer set to zero may have been legitimate. Is there a typical way of working around this sort of occurrence in go?

Comment: `""` is also a legitimate string. In Go, only pointer and interface values can be nil, so there really is no way to make a number nil.

Comment: Perhaps what you mean is [`zero value`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for number?

Comment: `nil` (or `null`/`NULL` in other languages) is not the same or a replacement of the empty string or of zero. It is a concept that represents the absence of any value, a value that is not known or a value that doesn't matter in the context. The empty string is an invalid person name but `nil` might be a perfectly valid value. It means the name is not known yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The "`nil`" value for a string `""` makes sense to me but `0` is a legitimate number.

There are two obvious problems with your statement:

1. There is no such thing as a **"`nil`" value for a string**.
2. `""` is a perfectly legitimate string.

You seem to be confusing Go's concept of a "zero value" with nil. These concepts are almost entirely unrelated.

- The zero value for a string is `""`.
- The zero value for a number is `0`.
- The zero value for a pointer or interface is `nil`.  This is the only place where `nil` and "zero values" really relate to each other.

Further strings, numbers, and other concrete types cannot ever be `nil` in Go.  (Pointers to these types can be, but that's obviously distinct).  So talking about a "nil value for a string" or "nil value for a number" doesn't even make sense.

---

In response to your edit, this question has already been answered in various contexts. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19633763/13860) for an example relating to JSON unmarshaling. In short, though, you must use something other than a number/string type. Use a pointer, or a wrapper type (such as a [sql.NullInt64](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#NullInt64)).

Answer (score 6):

A *designated* value from the set of *valid* values of the type have to be chosen. What else could qualify more for the position to be the [zero-value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)?

`nil` is not a valid value of numerical types (such as `int`, `uint`, `int32` etc.), so that's out of the question.

`0` has the benefit that in binary representation it's full zeros. It's name is also in line with *"zero value"*.

Maybe `-1`? `-1` in binary representation is full ones (using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation). `-1` is not any more special.

Then maybe the min value? In case of `int32` that would be `-1 << 31` which is `-2147483648`. But if the type is unsigned, e.g. `uint32`, that would again be `0`. Moreover, taking the type `int` the min value is not even a constant as it depends on the target architecture (may be `-1 << 31` and `-1 << 63`).

If `0` is a value you use and you want to differentiate whether it has already been set (or if the value is just being the zero value), use a pointer (e.g. `*int`) which may have a `nil` value (the zero value) indicating it has not yet been set.

Another option is to use a second variable (may be of type `bool`), it's `true` value indicating the number has been set.

Also more techniques (choosing a clever, non-used valid value), check out [How do I represent an Optional String in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30731687/how-do-i-represent-an-optional-string-in-go/30741287#30741287)

Answer (score 4):

For `string`, the default value is `""`; for `bool`, the default value is `false`; for `int`, the default value is `0`.

You can use pointer.

```
var num *int
if num == nil {
    // num is not set
} else {
    // num is set
    if *num == 0 {
        // num is set to 0
    } else {
        // num is set to another integer
    }
}
```

In the same way, you can judge if a boolean value is set or not.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a typical way of working around this sort of occurrence in go?

Whether an empty string or a zero is a valid/invalid value depends on the application. An empty name might be invalid for your application, but it might be valid in other cases.

A way to handle this in Go is by creating a struct and in there represent whether you have the value or not. For example:

```
type Person struct {
  Name    string
  HasName bool
  Age     int
  HasAge  bool
}
```

This seems a bit cumbersome for such a contrived example, but in more complex scenarios the overhead of having the extra field is minimal.