# Strict JSON parsing

Tags: json, go

When parsing JSON with Go, is it possible to fail if a value is null or missing, without having to check every single field via an if statement?
For example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Bird struct {
    Species     string `json:"birdType"`
    Description string `json:"what it does"`
}

func main() {
    birdJson := `{"birdType": "pigeon"}`
    var bird Bird
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(birdJson), &bird)
    fmt.Println(bird)
}
```

I'd expect to raise an error since `"what it does"` is not defined

Comment: Go doesn't throw, you should instead check the error returned by `json.Unmarshal`. To the specifics of your question though, the feature you're looking for is not implemented by `encoding/json`. You can instead validate the struct's fields after you are done unmarshaling. And in case you need the reverse, i.e. return error if json contains unknown fields, that is actually [possible](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17#Decoder.DisallowUnknownFields).

Comment: So I'd have to do that for every single field?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Are there any libraries, which could do that for me at all? This seems like quite a big feature missing :/. Also, could you add an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: There are libraries that do that, I don't use any of them so I can't recommend any, but if you search for "go validate" or "validation" or something like that you should get a bunch of suggestions in the results. Even here on SO, many people who use those libs often post questions about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [`encoding/json.Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.17#Unmarshal) will not return an error if the target struct has fields for which the source json does not contain any matching object keys.