# Unable to validate jsonschema in Go

Tags: json, go, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a request body that should be validated against specific schema.

There will be one optional property `returnValues` which is boolean should be validated if present in the `params` inside payload.

**Schema:**

```
{
   "title":"RPCRequest",
   "type":"object",
   "properties":{
      "params":{
         "description":"rpc method parameters",
         "type":"object",
         "additionalProperties":true
      }
   },
   "required":[
      "params"
   ],
   "additionalProperties":false
}
```

Although I mentioned `"additionalProperties": true`, I'm still getting that additional Property is not allowed error.

> RPC Parameters Validation Errors: [returnValues: Additional property
> returnValues is not allowed]

**Code:**

```
gojsonschema.Validate(schema, gojsonschema.NewGoLoader(params))


type GetChartRequest struct {
    ID           string
    Name         string
    Deployment   string
    Namespace    string
    Repository   string
    Version      string
    Cluster      string
    InstallOrder *uint64 `json:"installOrder"`
    Provider     string
    ReturnValues bool    `json:"returnValues"`
}
```

Comment: What is your relevant Go struct, that JSON is decoding to?

Comment: added in question

Comment: You can use boo pointer to `ReturnValues` values. Then default value is nil and then you can validate it whther it is nil or not. If `returnValues` present in the json, that should be not nil and otehrwise nil

Comment: No. Didn't work.

Comment: Can you add some reproducible example? Some example of JSON?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/68935566/4466350

Comment: @Underoos please share you json for which you are validating

Comment: Guys. Don't bother. This issue has been resolved. I just voted to close the question.

Comment: @Underoos instead of closing it would be helpful for others if you post the solution